# wrapprespective on android and c++ have different effect

Tags: android, opencv

Here is my c++, opencv code, which is basically overlaying an image at specified position on cameraFeed.

```
Mat transmix = getPerspectiveTransform(imagePoints, newLEDPoints);
            warpPerspective(repImage, cameraFeed, transmix, cameraFeed.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR,   cv::BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
```

Here imagePoints and newLEDPoints are two vectors containing exactly four Cartesian points in proper order. I am trying to achieve similar effect in android, opencv here is the code

read image in drawable

```
try {
        repImage = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.ring, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now for each frame

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCameraFrame");
    cameraFeed = inputFrame.rgba();
    Point center = new Point(cameraFeed.width()/2, cameraFeed.height()/2);
    Point topLeft = new Point( center.x - 100, center.y - 100 );
    Point topRight = new Point( center.x + 100, center.y - 100);
    Point bottomRight = new Point( center.x + 100, center.y + 100 );
    Point bottomLeft = new  Point( center.x - 100, center.y + 100 );
    List<Point> LEDPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    LEDPoints.add( topLeft );
    LEDPoints.add( topRight );
    LEDPoints.add( bottomRight );
    LEDPoints.add( bottomLeft );
    Log.i(TAG, "Before LEDPoint Conversion");
    Mat LEDPointss = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat( LEDPoints );

    List<Point> imagePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    imagePoints.add( new Point( 0, 0));
    imagePoints.add( new Point( repImage.width(), 0 ));
    imagePoints.add( new Point( repImage.width(), repImage.height()));
    imagePoints.add( new Point( 0, repImage.height()));
    Log.i(TAG, "Before imagePoint Conversion");
    Mat imagePointss = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat( imagePoints );

    Log.i(TAG, "Before transmix");
    Mat transmix = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(imagePointss, LEDPointss);

    Log.i(TAG, "Before warp");


    if ( !repImage.empty())
    {
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(repImage, 
            cameraFeed,
            transmix,
            cameraFeed.size(), 
            Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "repImage is empty");
    }
    Scalar color = new Scalar( 0, 255, 0 );
    Core.circle(cameraFeed, center, 10, color, 2);

    return cameraFeed;
}
```

I am just getting repImage on screen when I run this on my android tablet. I actually want repImage to appear on cameraFeed at stipulated co-ordinates ( as my c++ code does ) Please guide me what am I missing ? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm new to opencv ,but I think Core.circle is a drawing function (not data manipulation one) and it takes cameraFeed as input.

Comment: The two transmix are the same in C++ and Java?

Comment: @Toris circle is to test if something could be written on camera frame. if the line wrapPrespective is commented the circle is written on camera frame. So this line is for testing only.

Comment: @Miki they have different effect in this case. I might be missing something, can you please take a second look.

Comment: @Prem >they have different effect in this case  May be endian problem? (Java: big endian, c: little endian)

Comment: @Toris I am a bit new to all ( c++, opencv and android or java programming) can you please guide me how can i get similar effect in android, as my c++ code does. my c++ code simply displays repImage on top of camera feed. My android code ( which i think i wrote with the same logic ) displays repImage only at stipulated position. Android code doesn't show cameraFeed. How can I show both in android?

Comment: Post your C++ code too. There's no problem of endianness here